# Xdebug: Script resume running automatically in the background after the IDE is minimized for a few minutes

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm 2020.1.4 together with Xdebug 2.6.1 on Docker 2.3.0.3 (45519) on a Mac with OSX 10.15.6

- I set a breakpoint in my code, the debugger stops there as expected.
- I put a browser in the front to check something for a few minutes.
- I go back to PhpStorm.

The debugging has stopped, but the script is still running. I know that, because I can see that there are changes happening in the database.

I want that I can come back to PhpStorm and the debugger still hangs at the same breakpoint as it was before I put my browser (or any other program) in the front.

Does anybody know how to archive that?

Here is my Xdebug configuration:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"

xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/var/www/vhosts/my-site/logs/profiler
xdebug.profiler_output_name=%R
```

Comment: How do you debug it: is this a CLI or a web page? If web page -- what web server that is?

Comment: It is a webpage and I debug PHP. The server is amazon linux with apache I guess.

Comment: Not an IDE issue. As I see it's a Docker container... You have to configure your Docker/container then. See this thread (last comment in particular). https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000056364-Xdebug-continue-from-breakpoint-after-5-minutes

Comment: This seems to be due to Docker dropping idle TCP connections. Modifying `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json` and changing the value of `vpnKitMaxPortIdleTime` fixes the issue for me. Setting to `0` seems to indicate infinite. Additional reading: 1) https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2197#issuecomment-359866362 2) https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2406

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's a Mac and a Docker container.

This seems to be due to Docker dropping idle TCP connections. Modifying `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json` and changing the value of `vpnKitPortMaxIdleTime` should fix the issue. Setting to `0` seems to indicate infinite.

Additional reading:

- https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2197#issuecomment-359866362
- https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2406
- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2639 (for Windows)

**P.S.** Original solution is from [this PhpStorm Forums thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000056364-Xdebug-continue-from-breakpoint-after-5-minutes).